# How can I access to UI Text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to set my UI text from my script. I can access with public Text but I want to access with private game object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WebsiteAd : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject name;

    void Awake()
    {
        name = GameObject.Find("/Item0/Name");          
    }

    void Start()
    {
        name.GetComponent<Text>().text = "My Text";
    }
```

My Hierarchy
[image: Hierarchy]

Comment: what is your question? is the "name" variable null? what does not work?

Comment: Yes. Name is null, I can access to main objects of canvas with this method. But I cant access to parent objects.

Comment: Find does not return inactive game objects. If you really dont want to set the variable in editor, consider using any other find function that does return inactive objects. One of these functions is: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GameObject.Find](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) documentation states: "This function only returns active gameobjects."

In order to get access to inactive game objects, you need to use a function which supports them, like [GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html).

```
public Component[] GetComponentsInChildren(Type type, bool includeInactive = false);
```